# How to position a div outside other div?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to position a div with an image outside my main Card component. I have tried using margin-bottom, however, it didn't work. How can it be done using CSS styled-component?

I will attach an image here of the design that I'm trying to achieve:]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RT3a.jpg

**Card Component:**

```
function CardComponent(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <CardImage>{props.img}</CardImage>
        <CardName>{props.name}</CardName>
        <Description>{props.description}</Description>
        <Links>
          <Button>{props.livePreview}</Button>
          <Button>{props.github}</Button>
        </Links>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default CardComponent;
```

**Styled Component**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Card = styled.div`
  width: 25%;
  height: 70vh;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin-top: 5%;

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

export const CardImage = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid pink;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: auto;
`;

export const CardName = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
`;

export const Description = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;

export const Links = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  justify-content: center;
`;

export const Button = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid blue;
`;
```

Comment: So you mean showing the image outside its container to the top?

Comment: You can use `position: absolute` instead of margin-bottom, in this case, margin-bottom won't work as the top of the container will also extend as you try to move the image to the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `position: absolute` or `margin-top` to achieve it. Check the snippet attached:

```css
section {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

img {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://media1.popsugar-assets.com/files/thumbor/_Rrjw5u5qeqlO8Zznc0TskZB_8k/fit-in/1024x1024/filters:format_auto-!!-:strip_icc-!!-/2018/04/30/868/n/1922283/1f2e59ed5ae773b06f2879.82877284_/i/Does-Iron-Man-Die-Avengers-Infinity-War.jpg" />
  <h4>Hello world</h4>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
position:absolute;
top: -50;
```

Something like this should work, you should use absolute position because elements are overlapping each other and giving margin, padding etc. won't work since they are not meant to be overlap elements.